# ListView outputs stuff that I don't want

Tags: android, xml, listview

So I want the ListView to output lines of text and have buttons at the bottom. The code however, in ListView, prints text and duplicate buttons. How do I fix this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="122dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="122dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="380dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />



<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="button"
    android:id="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

java code

`ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.manage,R.id.textView2, String_array);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: At a guess you are showing the layout that is used by the adapter. The layout passed to the adapter is shown per item in the list. Again based on that guess you need to have a specific layout for each entry which is the layout that the adapter uses. It would assist if you included the names of the layouts in the question.

Answer (score 0):

What is the  content of file R.layout.manage, and where does listView come from? is it `listView = findViewById(R.id.listview2)`? You had better to post the whole relevant information when you ask question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question, do you want each row of the ListView to display a text and a button?

If so, you should create a separate layout for the ListView row, like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="122dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="122dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button"
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then extend an Adapter, so you can inflate this layout in each row, and set this custom adapter in your ListView.